Cannot curl to docker chainguard node server using fastify at http://[::1]:80
I have set up a docker container from chainguard running a node server with fastify.
The docker container shows as running:

Server listening at http://[::1]:80
Process id: 7

When I go to localhost I get no response. Also curl at localhost returns nothing.
Multi stage build - part 3 - of dockerfile
# ...
#  3rd part of build layer
FROM cgr.dev/chainguard/node:latest

ENV PATH=/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /app
# /app/node_modules
COPY --from=build-deps --chown=node:node /usr/src/app . 

# /app/dist/node-server.js
COPY --from=build-dist --chown=node:node /usr/src/app/dist dist

ENV NODE_ENV=production
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "dist/node-server.js"]


node-server.js
import Fastify from "fastify";
const server = Fastify();

server.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ message: "Success" });
});

const closeGracefully = async (signal) => {
  console.log(`Received signal to terminate: ${signal}`)
  await server.close()
  process.kill(process.pid, signal);
}
process.once('SIGINT', closeGracefully)
process.once('SIGTERM', closeGracefully)

const init = async () => {
  try {
    server.listen({ port: 80 }, (err, address) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      console.log(`Server listening at ${address}`);
    });
    console.log(`Process id: ${process.pid}`);
  } catch (err) {
    server.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

init();


localhost is different for the host and each docker container.  You can't just listen on localhost.  read about docker networking here https://docs.docker.com/engine/network/

...in the server.listen() call you might need an option like host: '0.0.0.0'.  Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip has some more explanations.  The listening at [::1] message with the IPv6 loopback address is a red flag indicating this kind of problem.
